# how can i run unix command inside a makefile?

Tags: unix, makefile

First I have no idea what I am doing so sorry if the question is absurd.

I have a makefile I run at work. The command line for it is:

make -f libclmcomm.so.mak

At the start of this file I want to issue a unix command. Let's just start with echo hi.

So I edited my file and typed:

echo hi

at the type but when I run my make command I get the following error:

missing seperator

Comment: You can't just put random commands in random spots in a `makefile` - it's not anything at all like a shell script, but has a very specific syntax that you probably ought to spend some time learning...

Answer (score 1):

StackOverflow is for specific questions, not tutorials.  I recommend you read the GNU make manual to understand what make is and how it works: http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/index.html

Your question really doesn't make sense as related to make.  Make runs commands that build targets.  Every command it runs must be associated with a target to be built.  That's why adding a command at the beginning doesn't work: a makefile is not a shell script (if you just want to run a bunch of commands in order the same way every time, then make is not the tool for you: just write a script).

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the command in the right place.  It is probably good enough to search through the file for the first line that is indented (with a tab) and place 'echo hi' (also indented with a tab) before that line.  Very likely, this will appear after an unindented line that includes the text `all:`.